# Why appending is returning None

Tags: python

I'm trying to swap keys and values, and append the keys if the values are duplicated.
But When trying to append the result is None.

```
def swap_keys_and_values(d):
    new_d = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if new_d.get(v):
            print(new_d.get(v), k)
            print(new_d.get(v).append(k))
            new_d[v] = new_d.get(v)
            new_d[v] = list(k) 
    return new_d
    
    print(swap_keys_and_values({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}))
```

['a'] c
None
{1: ['c'], 2: ['b']}

Comment: That's what it's supposed to return, that's what the docs say and is the convention for mutating methods. Why did you think it _wouldn't_?

Comment: Its common for methods that modify a collection to return `None`. What should they return? There isn't any clear cut answer to that. Returning a value that is simply discarded adds a minor reference count penalty to each append so it shouldn't be done "just in case".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.append()` is an in-place operation, it modifies the object it is called on.

Some in-place operations will return the object itself (and this is desirable for allowing method-chaining), but the basic list methods of Python do not have this behaviour (favouring speed and minimalism over usability for programmers).

All functions (and thus methods) return some result, but if no specific result is returned, the return value is `None`, which is the case here.

Note that having an in-place method can be confusing to a developer - they may assume that because the function is returning a modified value, the original was left unmodified and they have been provided with a copy of it. This is a conflict of two programming styles - neither is technically wrong, but mixing them can lead to very confusing code.

For example:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3]
ys = xs.returning_append(0).sort()
```

Here, a `0` is appended to the list `[1, 2, 3]`, but does `xs` change? And does `sort()` also return a value and is the value of `ys` now `[0, 1, 2, 3]` or `None`?

Python favours:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3]
xs.append(0)
xs.sort()
```

And if you don't want `xs` to change:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3]
ys = xs.copy()
ys.append(0)
ys.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

`append()` is a `list` method, not a `dict` method. You need to make sure you have a list first, and then set that list into the dictionary.

If you intend for each value in the new dict to be a list of all the previous keys that had that value, then you should use:

```py
values = new_d.get(v, [])
values.append(k)
new_d[v] = values   # required, as getting a list by default from .get() won't set the value for that key to the empty list.
```

If you use `new_d = defaultdict(list)` with defaultdict from the collections library, you could condense these 3 lines to the single line of `new_d[v].append(k)`